# Android: Communicating Between Fragments but with using back button as navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have the following situation and I'm not 100% sure how to solve it right it. It basically involves communication between the back button and two fragments.

Here is a Short Diagram

```
(Fragment1)        (Fragment2)       (Back button)
List of Recipes -> Recipe Filters -> List of Recipes
```

Obviously I'm doing addToBackStack etc. but I'm trying to rely on the back button for navigation instead of using the home button as I'm using that for a navigation drawer action right now.

Is there any way to pass information between fragment 1 / fragment 2 on a back button navigation action?

If not, what should be done instead. I'd like to avoid spawning an activity for the filters fragment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) and put whatever logic you want there.Code sample:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code to be executed when user presses back
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

Make sure you implement onBackPressed properly and they are no side effects.

Comment: That doesn't seem very extendable, considering if the activity has a lot of fragments. Then you'd have to keep checking....

Comment: @amchang87 you can use Command design pattern for neat implementation.refer-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: I decided just to avoid this and instead just a confirm button instead, too much management from the activity. Thanks